# Upgraded my JQGrid to latest version - now delete row function not working - MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

My delete row doesn't work anymore. Seems that whatever is coming back to the controller action in the FormCollection is now null. Have tried a number of things to no avail. Any ideas? Here is my js for the delete options:

```
     {reloadAfterSubmit: false, closeOnEscape: true, closeAfterAdd: true, url: '/EquipTrack/DeleteTool/', mtype: "POST",
     afterSubmit: function(response, postdata) {

         curToolRow = null;

         if (response.responseText == "Success") {
             jQuery("#tool_success").show();
             jQuery("#tool_success").html("Tool successfully deleted");
             jQuery("#tool_success").fadeOut(6000);

             return [true, response.responseText]
         }
         else {
             return [false, response.responseText]
         }
     },
     mtype: "POST", serializeDelData: function(postdata) {
         return ""; // the body MUST be empty in DELETE HTTP requests
     }, onclickSubmit: function(params) {
         var ajaxData = {};

         var rowData = $("#toolgrid").getRowData(curToolRow);

         ajaxData = { id: '1', oper: 'del', ToolID: rowData.tool_id };

         return ajaxData;
     }
 }, // del options
```

Here is my Controller action EditTool:

```
   [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult EditTool(Nullable<int> id, FormCollection formValues)
    {

        uls_dbDataContext db = new uls_dbDataContext();

        try
        {
            string strOper = formValues.GetValues("oper")[0];
            string strToolID = formValues.GetValues("ToolID")[0];

            tool tool;

            string strId = Convert.ToString(id);

            if (strOper == "del")
            {
                string strID = formValues.GetValues("id")[0];
                tool = db.tools.Single(t => t.tool_id == strId);

                db.tools.DeleteOnSubmit(tool);
            }

            db.SubmitChanges();


            return Content("Success");

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get the built in delete function working. I realize this should be straightforward but whatever I tried I was getting back nulls in my controller action. I wound up using my own modal dialog which was launched on the click of the delete icon I put on the grid tray. This works fine so I am closing this issue.

Comment: After further investigating I found the issue. I had to remove this: mtype: "POST", serializeDelData: function(postdata) {
         return ""; // the body MUST be empty in DELETE HTTP requests} from my jqgrid delete options. In the first version of the grid this was required. Apparently now it breaks the delete.